# SQL Select Case When Count > 1

Tags: sql, date, select, case, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks like the below.

```
ParentID | PersonID | Year 
----------------------------  
1             1       2019
1             2       2020
3             3       2019
3             4       2020
5             5       2019
```

I'm trying to figure out how to select the current PersonID when a ParentID has more than one record so my results would look like the below.

```
ParentID | PersonID | Year 
----------------------------  
1             2       2020
3             4       2020
5             5       2019
```

I can't select just the max PersonID because we sometimes create Person records for the previous year, in which case the PersonID is greater, and we still want to return this year's record. I also can't select based on year, because if they don't have a record for this year, we still need their most recent record for each ever year that is.

I've tried selecting this subset in half a dozen ways at this point and have only managed to make my brain hurt. Any assistance would be appreciated!!

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical greatest-n-per-group problem. To solve it, you need to think *filtering* rather than *aggregation*.

A portable solution is to filter with a correlated subquery that returns the latest `year` per `parent_id`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.year = (
    select max(t1.year) from mytable t1 where t1.parent_id = t.parent_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MSSQL, this can be achieved by `ROW_NUMBER`. You can read more about `ROW_NUMBER` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The `PARTITION BY` divides the result into partitions and apply row numbers to the partitions. So, applying partition to `ParentId` and sorting with `Year` descending, the data sorted `ParentId` by `Year`. Then remove the older data by using the `RowNo = 1` condition.

```
Create Table Test(ParentId int, PersonId int, Year int);
INSERT INTO Test values 
(1, 1, 2019), 
(1, 2, 2020),
(3, 3, 2019),
(3, 4, 2020), 
(5, 5, 2019);

SELECT ParentId, PersonId, Year FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ParentId 
  ORDER BY Year /* Use PersonId if it fits correctly */ DESC) AS RowNo,
  ParentId, PersonId, Year from Test -- Table Name
 ) E WHERE ROWNo = 1
```